# Android Модель данных, как можно получить один элемент?

Tags: java, android, list

Я создал модель данных 
**Person.java**

```
public class Person {

long id;
String blzn;
String prich;
String affirm;

// пустой конструктор
public Person() {
}

// конструктор с переменными
public Person( long id, String blzn, String prich, String affirm) {

    this.id = id;
    this.blzn = blzn;
    this.prich = prich;
    this.affirm = affirm;
}
}
```

В **MainActivity.java**

Загружаю данными из ресурса

```
    List<Person> persons;

        Resources res = getResources();
    String[] blzn = res.getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);
    String[] prich = res.getStringArray(R.array.cat_names2);
    String[] affirm = res.getStringArray(R.array.cat_names3);

    int length = blzn.length;
    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        persons.add(new Person(i, bolezn[i], prich[i],  affirm[i]));
    }
```

Как теперь во втором активити загрузить один элемент данных например из колонки `prich` третий элемент

**LastActivity.java**

```
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

title.setText(???);
```

Comment: Я через intent получаю число         // извлекаем из него объект
        idString = intent.getStringExtra("id");
        // конвертируем id в число
        idInt = Integer.parseInt(idString);

intent  из адаптара. 
Модель данных заполняю в MainActivity, в адаптаре обрабатываю, по клику на item, открывается LastActivity где я принимаю число.
Как-то так

Comment: У вас есть коллекция объектов-моделей, модели там расположены в определенном порядке и можно получить модель из определенной позиции в этой коллекции. Так же в модели у вас есть поле ID. Это тоже идентификатор. По какому из этих идентификаторов вам нужно получить "третий элемент" - по позиции в коллекции или по ID в модели.

Comment: "третий" - это просто для примера. Так я получаю по id, Но я думаю может тем же способом, что я id передаю передать и весь остальной текст из адаптара, не знаю правильно это или нет, сейчас поробую

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам необходимо дописать геттеры для `Person` и обращаться следующим образом:

```
    // У первой активности
    List<Person> persons;

    Resources res = getResources();
    String[] blzn = res.getStringArray(R.array.cat_names);
    String[] prich = res.getStringArray(R.array.cat_names2);
    String[] affirm = res.getStringArray(R.array.cat_names3);

    int length = blzn.length;
    persons = new ArrayList<>();

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("PERSONS_LIST", personList);
startActivity(intent);

// У второй активности
ArrayList<Person> personlist = 
    (ArrayList<Person>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("PERSONS_LIST");

    title.setText(persons.get(index).getPrich());
```

Либо вместо всего листа, можно передать лишь нужный параметр одиночно:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("prich", person.get(index).getPrich());
startActivity(intent);

//во второй активити

String prich = getIntent().getExtras("prich");
```

Comment: Ошибку выдал. Во втором Активити достаточно написать вначале     List<Person> persons; может еще что-то нужно дописать??

Comment: @Artsait невнимательно прочёл, вам надо из второго активити достать. Сейчас дополню ответ.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, сейчас поробую, примерно так и сделать. Я данные получаю даже не с MfainActivity, а из адаптара. Верней заполняю модель данных в Активити, затем передаю все это адаптару, а из адаптара ужу открывается LastActivity, где я и могу получить данные. Но я так понял, что напрямую без intent данные не могу получить, как например из БД, нужно именно передовать?

Comment: @Artsait я не совсем понял о чем вы.

Comment: Все получилось! Спасибо Вам большое))))

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу @Asgard

**Person.java**

```
public class Person {
    long id;
    String blzn;
    String prich;
    String affirm;

    // пустой конструктор
    public Person() {
        this(null, null, null, null)
    }

    // конструктор с переменными
    public Person( long id, String blzn, String prich, String affirm) {
        this.id = id;
        this.blzn = blzn;
        this.prich = prich;
        this.affirm = affirm;
    }

    // возврат id
    public long getId () {
        return id;
    }

    // возврат prich
    public String getPrich () {
        return prich;
    }    
}
```

Нужно перебрать все элементы списка и сравнить их через метод `.getId` (или иной). Дальше получить нужное значение экземпляра класса через `.getPrich`

В LastActivity.java можно будет поставить результат следующего действия:

```
long id = ...; // Идентификатор, по которому нужно найти определённый экземпляр класса модели 
String prich = null; // Переменная для полученного результата с prich
for (Person person : persons) { // Перебираем все элементы списка persons
    if (person.getId() == id) {    // Если id совпадают
        prich = person.getPrich(); // тогда берём значение
        break;                     // и завершаем цикл
    }
}
```

Далее передаём полученное значение переменной `prich` в **LastActivity.java**

Comment: Не верно, здесь не хватает перехода на следующую активити, и достать экстрас из интента

Comment: @Asgard Тут еще и не ясно какой "третий элемент" имеется ввиду - ID модели или позиция в коллекции, чтобы писать ответ.

Comment: @pavlofff написал шаблоны как можно, а там уже пусть сам ищет более подходящую реализацию.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сейчас поробую разобраться